# programmatically submit form via drupal_form_submit causing WSOD

Tags: 7, forms, wsod

I hate the title to my question but this is basically what is happening. WSOD is killing me and I can not figure this one out.

Basically what i am doing is attempting to have any user navigate to a url that would build a form, submit it and generate a graph.

for example

```
http://server/data-points/bade/bcharts/datacenter=rr&device=pdu total&startdate=2012-09-26 10:43&enddate=2012-09-27 10:43
```

so from the second menu path below in the `hooks_menu()` function, this should call `bcharts_directBuild()` with all the data after `/data-points/bade/bcharts/%`.  `bcharts_directBuild` is calling `drupal_form_submit` but seems to WSOD every time. `watchdog` is not giving me anything and all erroring is enabled. Is there something I'm missing here?

I would also like to point out that `datacenter_devices` is dependent on which `datacenter` you are selecting. so there is an ajax call in there. and also `bcharts_directBuild` has been hard coded just for testing purposes.

Here is my code

```
function bcharts_menu() {

$items['data-points/bade/bcharts'] = array(
        'title'             => 'Data Charts',
        'page callback'     => 'bcharts_page',
        'access arguments'  => array('access content'),
        'file'              => 'bade_charts.inc',
);


$items['data-points/bade/bcharts/%'] = array(
        'page callback'     => 'bcharts_directBuild',
        'page arguments'    => array(3),
        'access arguments'  => array('access content'),
        'file'              => 'bade_charts.inc',
);

return $items;
}

function bcharts_form($form, &$form_state) {

global $dcEquipment; 

$datacenterOptions = _bcharts_datacenterOptions($dcEquipment);

isset($form_state['values']['datacenter']) ?
    $datacenterSelect = $form_state['values']['datacenter'] : $datacenterSelect = 'Ridge Rd';

isset($form_state['values']['datacenter_devices']) ?
    $DCDeviceSelect = $form_state['values']['datacenter_devices'] : $DCDeviceSelect = '';

// Calculate the start date for default value
isset($form_state['values']['start_date']) ?
    $currentDate = $form_state['values']['start_date'] : $currentDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

// Calculate the end date for default value. This is plus one day.
isset($form_state['values']['end_date']) ?
    $lastdayDate = $form_state['values']['end_date'] :  $lastdayDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")) - 86400);


// Start Date for the form
$form['start_date'] = array(
    '#type'             => 'date_popup',
    '#title'            => 'Start Date',
    '#date_format'      => 'Y-m-d H:i',
    '#date_increment'   => 1,
    '#date_year_range'  => '-2:0',
    '#default_value'    => $lastdayDate,
    '#required'         => TRUE,
);

// End Date for the form
$form['end_date'] = array(
    '#type'             => 'date_popup',
    '#title'            => 'End Date',
    '#date_format'      => 'Y-m-d H:i',
    '#date_increment'   => 1,
    '#date_year_range'  => '-2:0',
    '#default_value'    => $currentDate,
    '#required'         => TRUE,
);


// Datacenter drop down
$form['datacenter'] = array(
    '#type'             => 'select',
    '#title'            => 'Datacenter',
    '#options'          => $datacenterOptions,                      
    '#default_value'    => $datacenterSelect,                               
    '#required'         => TRUE,
    '#ajax'             => array(
            'callback'  => '_bcharts_equipmentCallback',
            'wrapper'   => 'datacenter-devices',
    ),
);

$form['datacenter_devices'] = array(
    '#type'             => 'select',
    '#title'            => $datacenterSelect. ' ' .t('Datacenter Devices'),
    '#prefix'           => '<div id="datacenter-devices">',
    '#suffix'           => '</div>',
    '#required'         => TRUE,
    '#options'          => _bcharts_getDatacenterDevices($dcEquipment, $datacenterSelect),
    '#default_value'    => $DCDeviceSelect,
);

// Normal Submit button
$form['submit'] = array(
    '#type'     => 'submit',
    '#value'    => t('Display'),
);

$form['results'] = array(
    '#type'     => 'item',
    '#markup'   => '<div id="chartdiv" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>',
);

return $form;
}

function bcharts_directBuild($args = '') {

$form_state = array();

$form_state['values']['datacenter']             = 'rr';
$form_state['values']['datacenter_devices']     = 'ups total';
$form_state['values']['start_date']             = '2012-09-26 10:43'; 
$form_state['values']['end_date']               = '2012-09-27 10:43';
$form_state['values']['op']                     = t('Display');

drupal_form_submit('bcharts_form', $form_state);

$errors = form_get_errors();
if (!empty($errors)) {
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        $msg = 'Error: %error';
        $var = array('%error' => $error);
        watchdog('bcharts', $msg, $var, WATCHDOG_ERROR);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: What is the error in the Apache logs?

Comment: nothing in the logs

Comment: It appears that your url is somewhat malformed, eg, you don't start off your query variables/arguments with a `?=` but jump right in with an `=`.  Could this be squirreling things up even before it gets to drupal?

Comment: i doubt it. regardless if i've gotten the url to be acceptable or not, how would you handle this? if i do something like `http://server/data-points/bade/bcharts?datacenter=rr&device=pdu total&startdate=2012-09-26 10:43&enddate=2012-09-27 10:43` the path is not actually picked up.